# Prevent Child Record Deletion?

Tags: apex, trigger, account, contact

I am trying to write a trigger for if we delete Account record corresponding contact record should not be deleted. I have the code to pass the error but not deleting.

```
trigger notdeleteconatct on Account(before delete) {

    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();  
    Set<id> accIdSet = new Set<id>();  
    for(Account acc : Trigger.old) {  
        accIdSet.add(acc.id);  
    }  

    Map<Id, Account> accts = new Map<Id, Account>([
            Select Id,
              (Select Id from contacts)
            From Account
            Where id in :accIdSet]);

    for(Account acc : Trigger.old) {
        if(accts.get(acc.id).contacts.size()>0) {
            //acc.adderror('Account cannot be deleted');
        }
    }                                       
}
```

Comment: Can we see your current trigger code?

Comment: Your above code will give you the custom validation error as expected. Am I reading this right by saying you do want to delete the Account but keep all Contacts? What do you plan on doing with these Contacts once the Account has been deleted?

Comment: Are you try to delete an Account or through an error while having contact?

Comment: I want to delete an account record but not corresponding Contact record. I think u may got my point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code which have same requirement as of yours

```
trigger PurchaseOrderTrigger on Purchase_order__c (before delete) {

    Set<id> setPOIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Purchase_order__c objPO:trigger.old)
        setPOIds.add(objPO.id);


    Map<Id,List<Serialized_Product__c>> mapLinkedSPs = new Map<Id,List<Serialized_Product__c>>();

    for(Serialized_Product__c objSP:[select id,Purchase_Order_Line_Item__c,Purchase_Order_Line_Item__r.Purchase_order__r.Id from Serialized_Product__c where Purchase_Order_Line_Item__r.Purchase_order__r.Id=:setPOIds]){

        if(mapLinkedSPs.containsKey(objSP.Purchase_Order_Line_Item__r.Purchase_order__r.Id)) {
            List<Serialized_Product__c> lstSPs = mapLinkedSPs.get(objSP.Purchase_Order_Line_Item__r.Purchase_order__r.Id);
            lstSPs.add(objSP);
            mapLinkedSPs.put(objSP.Purchase_Order_Line_Item__r.Purchase_order__r.Id, lstSPs);
        } else {
            mapLinkedSPs.put(objSP.Purchase_Order_Line_Item__r.Purchase_order__r.Id, new List<Serialized_Product__c> { objSP });
        }
    }
    for(Purchase_order__c objPO:trigger.old){

        if (mapLinkedSPs.containsKey(objPO.id)){
            objPO.adderror('You cannot delete the Purchase Order as Serialized Products are linked with it');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I am a trainee in my org my senior has told me that to do this even I too know without Account there is no use of contacts. but by using trigger how we can do if deletion of Account has happend contacts not be deleted

Comment: What you have to do is, just replace Purchase_order__c  by account and  Serialized_Product__c  by contact

Comment: Thank you for your code . But there is no need to raise validation error simply account will be delete if we del the record but not contact.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, for all contacts, those are connected to account, for them , you have to make account id for them null.